# Is it possible to call a custom directive in AngularJS from a JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to call a custom directive using the name from a JSON array instead of actually calling the directive directly. So, for example, I have a custom directive called AccessibilityRadio which dynamically creates radio buttons by using . I would like to use 
 
<{{field.customDirectiveName}}> and pull the value form the JSON array to call the custom directive. The problem is that when I do this I can only see the name of the custom directive on the browser access-bility-radio. So in my JSON array I have $scope.test.fields[{"customDirectiveName": "accessibility-radio"}]  - something like that.

Is it possible to call the custom directive as a json value instead of directly calling the custom directive from the form. Is there a better way to do this? Thank You

Comment: I've read your post several times and still unsure what you are asking for - are you saying you want to change some content with a custom directive dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the $compile service to handle on-the-fly changes to content containing other directives.

[Here's a trivial example](http://plnkr.co/edit/93xN6ZlVcsfML1lVSx5c?p=preview) of changing content with different directives.

The gist of the code is the wrapper directive, which replaces it's inner content with an element with name 'directiveName' via the $compile service.

```
.directive("wrapper", function($compile, $interval) {
    return {
      scope: {
        directiveName: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("directiveName", function() {
          var html = "<" + scope.directiveName + "></" + scope.directiveName + ">";
          elem.html(html);
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

The wrapper directive uses $watch to detect changes on the scope.directiveName, so when scope.directiveName changes the wrapper directive replaces its content with an element with name = scope.directiveName and compiles the content.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you very much. What if I wanted to add an ng-repeat to the dropdown or any other form element. What would need to be passed in. I am having issues populating the dropdown using ng-repeat from a scope variable. Can you please provide an example, because I am having issues from the template using http://plnkr.co/edit/93xN6ZlVcsfML1lVSx5c?p=preview . Thank you for your answer and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I had another question. Instead of creating a new controller in addition to the wrapper directive, what if I wanted to use the wrapper directive to call an existing custom directive without alternating different directives. so, in other words from the wrapper I wanted to pass in the name of the custom directive and just display the custom directive which was another directive not inside a controller. Something like <wrapper directive-name="test-directive"></wrapper><br/>and the html would get built based on another custom directive from the page not necessarily from a specific controller.

Comment: Glad it helped, consider *accepting* it as the answer.

Comment: It's best to post new questions to avoid detracting from this question.  Here's an [example plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VChPKH2GEUUqRrKkDyQC?p=preview) demonstrating ng-options based on the answer code.  To your second question, the controller in the answer code is only there to drive the directive change, the source of 'test-directive' is completely arbitrary, it's up to you how to elaborate the pattern.